# Inferencing and best fit

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning

Do you think I could use OWL reasoning to get of the following ontology a *sorted* result like:

1. JobSeeker2
2. JobSeeker1

or the new relations, something like this:

1. Vacancy1   -->   JobSeeker2
2. Vacancy1   -->   JobSeeker1

Because JobSeeker2 is the better fit because both pointing to the same skill but JobSeeker1 is also not bad because both have a relation to the parent concept OOP.

[image]

Comment: I don't think owl reasoning is appropriate for what you want to do. Reasoning doesn't provide ranking results. In your example, if you assert that "Java" is an "OOP", after applying reasoning you would obtian that "Java" is a "Programming" as well. I think that what it would suit you it would be a SPARQL query. Something like: `SELECT ?jobseeker WHERE{ ?vacancy needsSkill ?x. ?jobseeker hasSkill ?x}'. Although without inference, this query would only return JobSeeker2